# Is there a library similar to ITextSharp that produces a jpg from html snapshot?

Tags: c#, open-source, mono, jpeg, html-to-jpeg

I would like to create a server-side process that will capture html as an image and produce a jpeg.  My process will be running on Linux / Mono and I am not sure that I can use the Webform Image Control in memory as suggested in Peter [Bromberg's excellent article on EggHeadCafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b7cce396-e2b3-42d7-9571-cdc4eb38f3c1/build-a-selfcaching-asp.aspx).

Is there an open source framework similar to ITextSharp that can accomplish the rendering?

Comment: Are you restricting the solution to API libraries only or will a print driver work for you?

Comment: If I can get the print driver is Linux based and I can fire it off from my web server I can use it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

webSupergoo's [ABCpdf .NET](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-html.htm) renders HTML to JPG. Not open source, but can be obtained for free.